# Multiple imageView refreshing in Android using asynctasks?

Tags: android, multithreading, imageview, multimedia

what I have to do is to play videos on a single activity, the number of videos is undefined, could be from 1 to 8, a video in my case is an image sequence, where every image is downloaded from a cam on the internet using a fixed time interl.

Do a single video activity is not a problem, I can make it using ImageView and a AsyncTask, using many instances of this method when I try to make multiple videos activities does not work, only one of the video plays. I don't know exactly what it happens but I think it could be a cuncurrency related issue due to the UIThread.

Here the used AsyncTask code:

```
private class AsyncTask_LiveView extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> 
{   
    private String sImageMessage = "";

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private Bitmap bmImage = null;
    private String url = "";
    private String usr = "";
    private String pwd = "";
    private utils u = new utils();

    public AsyncTask_LiveView(ImageView imageView, String Url, String Usr, String Pwd)
    {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        url = Url;
        usr = Usr;
        pwd = Pwd;
    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) 
    {
        while(!isCancelled())
        {
            if(isCancelled())
                 return null;

            SystemClock.sleep(200);

            Log.v("ImageDownload","test");
            bmImage = u.DownloadBitmapFromUrl(url, usr, pwd);

            publishProgress(0);
        }

        return null;
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... i)
    {
        Log.v("Image", "Setup Image");
        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmImage);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I start the AsyncTasks in this way:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutliveviewdouble);

        this.imgV1 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    aTaskImgV1 = new AsyncTask_LiveView(imgV1,
                                        URL1,
                                        "",
                                        "");


    this.imgV2 = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    aTaskImgV2 = new AsyncTask_LiveView(imgV2,
                                        URL2,
                                        "root",
                                        "jenimex123");

    aTaskImgV1.execute();
    aTaskImgV2.execute();
}
```

The DownloadBitmapFromUrl method is:

```
public Bitmap DownloadBitmapFromUrl(String imageURL, final String usr, final String pwd) {  //this is the downloader method
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageURL); 


        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        ucon.setRequestMethod("GET");
        ucon.setDoOutput(true);
        Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication (usr, pwd.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        ucon.connect();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is =  ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(100000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baf.toByteArray(), 0, baf.length());

        return bmp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

**Solution : (21/01/11)**

The bounch of lines:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication (usr, pwd.toCharArray());
            }
        });
```

were braking the mechanism. In fact only one credentials pair a could have been set **globally**, and the other download processes stucked in requesting using the wrong credentials.

The solution is:

```
String authString = usr + ":" + pwd;
byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encode(authString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

if(_usr != "")
   ucon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: How do you start these AsyncTasks?

Comment: Could you show me the log around the place it got stuck (15-20 lines)?

Comment: I'll be away from work till thursday. I'll write the log around the moment I got stuck then. Thanks for be willing in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I think yuo should use unique `AsyncTask_LiveView` for each `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this function support multiple threads?

```
bmImage = u.DownloadBitmapFromUrl(url, usr, pwd);
```

Comment: The object "u" is a fresh instance in every AsyncTask, so I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the methods you call in downloadBitmapFromUrl(..) method involve synchronization by some common object. Try adding some extra logging to each part of this method and see where each thread gets stuck. I would do it this way:

```
public Bitmap downloadBitmapFromUrl(String imageURL, final String usr, final String pwd) {  //this is the downloader method
    try {
    ...
    Log.i(toString() + " in " + Thread.currentThread(), "is about to open connection...");
    HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    Log.i(toString() + " in " + Thread.currentThread(), "has opened connection");

    ...
```

and so on.

Comment: It came out that the other blocked AsyncTask (I test only the 2 video stream case) is stuck at

while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
        {
                baf.append((byte) current);
        }
again: Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.